# Node Sequelize mysql convert boolean field without <Buffer 00>

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I use mysql

I try to build a rest api.

I define a sequelize model,

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  return sequelize.define('unseuil', {
    id: {
      autoIncrement: true,
      type: DataTypes.BIGINT,
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true
    },
    actif: {
      type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: true
    },
    codeisin: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(20),
      allowNull: true
    },
    ...
```

I build 2 queries .

**First**

```
async function getListeSeuil(codeisin) {
    let liste = await db.unseuil.findAll({ where: { codeisin: codeisin }, order: [
                ['cours', 'ASC']
            ], raw : true });
```

result :

```
[
  {
    id: 2464,
    actif: <Buffer 00>,
    codeisin: 'LU1598757687',
    cours: 10.45,
    datecreation: 2020-07-22T11:57:52.000Z,
    description: 'Resistance'
  },
...
```

**Second**

```
async function getListeSeuil(codeisin) {
    let liste = await db.unseuil.findAll({ where: { codeisin: codeisin }, order: [
                ['cours', 'ASC']
            ] });
```

Result :

```
[
  unseuil {
    dataValues: {
      id: 2464,
      actif: false,
      codeisin: 'LU1598757687',
      cours: 10.45,
      datecreation: 2020-07-22T11:57:52.000Z,
      description: 'Resistance'
    },
    _previousDataValues: {
      id: 2464,
      actif: false,
      codeisin: 'LU1598757687',
      cours: 10.45,
      datecreation: 2020-07-22T11:57:52.000Z,
      description: 'Resistance'
    },
...
```

The dataValues are correct.

I work around and found a solution for this case.

I want an array with raw value and actif as a boolean.

What is the good way ?

Answer (score 0):

My first solution.

```
async function getListeSeuil2(codeisin) {
    let liste = await db.unseuil.findAll({ where: { codeisin: codeisin }, order: [
                ['cours', 'ASC']
            ], raw : true });

    // correctif d'un bug de reconstruction des booleans.
    var tab = [];
    for (var element of liste)
    {
        tab.push(element.dataValues);
    }
    return tab;
}
```